# How to automatically upload changed files over FTP

Tags: ftp, text-editors, sync

I have an IDE PyCharm for editing a Django application I am working on now. It has no FTP access and I work with a local copy of my application. Then I have to upload changed files to my production server over FTP. So, is that possible to automatically send updated files as they are changed? May be there are some utilities to make it?

UPD: I have created a webdav folder on my hosting and I have attached it as a network place in Windows XP. So, I see files in explorer inside the folder. Now I need to map this location as a drive. When I try to do this, I see the button OK becomes inactive so it won't let me know to add it or its inner folders as a drive.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

you can use "allwaysync" (free utility for windows) to sync folders
http://allwaysync.com/download.html
it can sync both locations, or you can select one as a source and one as a destination
can propagate and move modified / deleted files to user specified folders

very good and light weight - can be scheduled via task scheduler or windows batch.

Comment: Just tested allwaysync on a dev project, took 6 hours and i only wanted it to upload changed files. Now it scans the entire FTP each time a file gets changed and that takes an hour. I would not recommend this for anything other than backups.

Comment: AllWaySync is horribly old and confusing. It can do a lot but it has one of the worst UIs I've ever seen. SyncBack is a good alternative.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to directly edit the files on the production server then you can mount the relevant folders as a network drive via the windows explorer.

If you want to edit locally and upload all changes when you're done you could use rsync.

Answer (score 0):

PyCharm Professional Edition supports deploying files to FTP servers, and can do it automatically when files change or when you build:

http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/remote-hosts.html

http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/uploading-and-downloading-files.html

According to the [official editions comparison](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html), FTP upload isn't supported in the Community Edition.

Answer (score -1):

There is an ftp plugin for mercurial that you may be able to use in your workflow https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/FTPExtension

Comment: This 5 yr-old question doesn't mention using Mercurial, and your answer just suggests a product name with no information about it or how to use it to solve the problem, so your answer reads like spam.  Please read http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers for guidance on recommending software.